# Setting the viewbag value from the javascript function and accessing it from another js funnction

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I am having an MVC application. In the application I am calling a controller method from the javascript function using the below code:

```
function settingViewBagData(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home1/SetViewBag",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

Below is the controller method:

```
public void SetViewBag()
{
   ViewBag.data = "Test";
}
```

Now I want to access this viewbag data on another javascript function called on button click, which will be fired after the first function. Below is the javascript function for accessing the viewbag data:

```
function accessVal()
{ 
var variable3 = '@ViewBag.data';
alert(variable3);
 }
```

But I am getting blank in the alert box. Please help me to fix the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning View, so it will not show VIewBag. Do this:

```
public class Home1Controller : Controller
{
    // GET: Home1
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SetViewBag()
    {
        return Json(new { Msg = "Test" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The above is controller. Below is the index view:

```
//View    
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            settingViewBagData();
        });
        function settingViewBagData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home1/SetViewBag",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.Msg);
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            })
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it will work.